# Solr default search field for multiple fields which has different analyzers

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene

I have a document which has **title**, **stockCode**, **category** fields.

I have different field types (and analysis chains) for each. For instance **title** has EdgeNGram 2 to 20, **category** has EdgeNGram 3 to 10 with different range and **stockCode** just has lowercase filter.

So that, **I don't want to** search from documents with keyword "sample" with building the query like **title:sample OR stockCode:sample OR category:sample**.

**I'd like to** search with just "**q=sample**".

I copied my fields to *text* but It does not work. Because all fields analyzed as same. But I don't want to index stockCode as EdgeNGram or any other filters. I'd like to index my fields as I configured and I'd like to search a keyword over them base on my indexes.

I've been researching about that for three days, and Solr has a little bit poor documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `edismax` handler, as this will allow you to give a list of fields to query and supply the query by itself. You can also give separate weights to each field for scoring them differently.

```
defType=edismax&q=sample&qf=title^10 stockCode category
```

.. will search for `sample` in each of the three fields, giving a 10x boost to any hits in the `title` field.

You can [find the documentation about the edismax query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#the-extended-dismax-query-parser) under `Searching` in the reference guide.

Comment: I will check asap ;)